# QGIS Theme Night Mapping changing text color plugin

Tags: qgis

Where I have to adjust the color setting in the 'Night Mapping' theme to make the description text from the plugin/extension chooser/updater from black (= unreadable) to white?
[image: qgis_changecolor_plugin_blacktowhite]

Comment: Yo can change this theme in your qgis installation,for me is : ```C:\Users\francisco\.qgis2\themes\Night Mapping```